# GetSetting/SaveSetting and user rights

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the VBA GetSetting and SaveSetting functions in VBA for an Add-In that I am working on. My concern is that using these functions requires Read and Write RegistryPermissions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.getsetting(v=vs.110).aspx
However, I did not find any definite answer if regular users have this permission e.g. in the scope of setting they create through my Add-In. Please confirm if users will need admin rights to use these functions in my Add-In.

Comment: Regular users should have rights to that part of the registry.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Rory. Do you have any link to ms resources or something that reassures this?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid, but I have never had an issue with it. My understanding was that the whole point was that any installed code would have access to that portion of the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular i.e Standard user should not need admin right to use these functions.

It seems current user section of registry read/write access is required, which can be done by non-admin user.

Reference Link:

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135/what-registry-access-can-you-get-without-administrator-privleges) : access right for non-admin user.

[MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb0c3wb9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) : GetSetting Function

Comment: Thanks - the second link was especially useful!