# How to change system date format programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, date, format, system

I have a winforms application written in C#, I need to know how to change local system's date format from my application.

Will it require the application to run under administrator's permission ?

Comment: If you need to use a specific date format using actual local system date you may have a look at this doc from Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings. No need of administrator privilege for that.

Comment: @Mando Can you accept the answer if it helped you...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the date format in the registry:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International", true);

key.SetValue("sShortDate", "d/M/yy");
key.SetValue("sLongDate", "dd/MM/yy");
```

It might take a few seconds until you see it changed.

If you're only changing the registry for the current user you don't need admin privileges ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135/what-registry-access-can-you-get-without-administrator-privleges))