# How to read & write from registry without admin privileges_C#

Tags: c#, registry, privileges, administration

I need to write and read keys in Registry without administrator mode.First I want to know is this possible to do?

Please find below code (It's working fine, when Visual studio open in Administrator mode)

Write

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true);

key.CreateSubKey("AppName");
key = key.OpenSubKey("AppName", true);

key.CreateSubKey("AppVersion");
key = key.OpenSubKey("AppVersion", true);

key.SetValue("myval", "677");
key.Close();
```

---

Read

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true);

  key.CreateSubKey("AppName");
  key = key.OpenSubKey("AppName", true);
   //if it does exist, retrieve the stored values  
  if (key != null)
  {
    string s = (string)key.GetValue("myval");
    Console.Read();
    key.Close();
   }
```

Please any one suggest a way to do this.
(I tried to add below line as well)

**Error** :

> ClickOnce does not support the request execution level
>   'requireAdministrator'.

Comment: <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: `Registry.CurrentUser` ?

Comment: @john I need to add key in Registry.LocalMachine

Comment: So you want to access `LocalMachine` registry keys without administrator access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What registry access can you get without Administrator privleges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135/what-registry-access-can-you-get-without-administrator-privleges)

Comment: You can't write to HKLM without admin access. You can reduce the security levels on it to allow it to be done, but that also would require admin access and in addition would make your machine vulnerable. If you need something written to HKLM, write an installer and have the installation run by a user with admin privileges, write the key during the install, and leave the protection alone. Your app can then read from HKLM when being run as  a non-admin. (I'd suggest you do some searching before asking a question here. This same question has been asked (and answered) many times here before.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer on 
[how to write in registry without admin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46b8d4a8-a99c-4796-9b94-4d493aac6674/how-we-can-get-write-access-in-hklm-hkeylocalmachine-without-admin-account?forum=vcgeneral)

Reading is done by using the RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree option

```
    RegistryKey baseRegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(baseKey, RegistryView.Registry64);
    RegistryKey subRegistryKey = baseRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(subKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
    if (subRegistryKey != null)
    {
        object value64 = subRegistryKey.GetValue(value);
        if (value64 != null)
        {
            baseRegistryKey.Close();
            subRegistryKey.Close();
            return value64;
        }
        subRegistryKey.Close();
    }            
    baseRegistryKey.Close();
```

Then do the same with RegistryView.Registry32